# Monitor stopped working (after changing rotation). `EDID has corrupt header`. How do I fix? (And how can I even get a file with a *non*-corrupt EDID?)

Tags: drivers, hdmi, external-monitor, display-rotation, dvi

So my monitor stopped working,
when I was messing around with the the rotation
(ie `xrander -o [ normal, left, right, inverted ]` stuff).

(
The monitor input is DVI (DVI-D Dual Link),
and the laptop's output port is HDMI,
so they're connected with an adapter.
)

All (I think) of the relevant `dmesg` output:

```
 [Tue Aug 22 03:18:45 2023] [drm:radeon_dvi_detect [radeon]] *ERROR* HDMI-A-1: probed a monitor but no|invalid EDID  
 [Tue Aug 22 03:18:45 2023] [drm:radeon_dvi_detect [radeon]] *ERROR* HDMI-A-1: probed a monitor but no|invalid EDID  
 [Tue Aug 22 03:18:45 2023] EDID has corrupt header  
 [Tue Aug 22 03:18:45 2023]      [00] BAD  ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 7f 2f 3d 07 47 4e 5f 7b 3f  
 [Tue Aug 22 03:18:45 2023]      [00] BAD  17 01 03 ff 3f 1f 7f 3f ff 1f bf 7f 4f 9b 27 13  
 [Tue Aug 22 03:18:45 2023]      [00] BAD  70 7c bf ee ff 71 4f 81 00 97 00 ff 0f 9d 0f 01  
 [Tue Aug 22 03:18:45 2023]      [00] BAD  01 01 01 01 01 30 2a 40 c8 60 84 67 30 18 5f 13  
 [Tue Aug 22 03:18:45 2023]      [00] BAD  00 bb f9 10 00 00 1e 00 00 00 fd 00 38 4f 1e 71  
 [Tue Aug 22 03:18:45 2023]      [00] BAD  0f 00 0e 3f 20 20 3f 20 3f 00 00 00 fc 00 7f 7f  
 [Tue Aug 22 03:18:45 2023]      [00] BAD  7f 33 3f 3f 3f 0e 3f 3f 3f 3f 20 00 00 00 ff 00  
 [Tue Aug 22 03:18:45 2023]      [00] BAD  4f 77 4f 42 3f 3f 30 32 30 3f 0e 20 3f 01 b7 02  
 [Tue Aug 22 03:18:46 2023] EDID block 0 (tag 0x00) checksum is invalid, remainder is 190  
 [Tue Aug 22 03:18:46 2023] [drm:radeon_dvi_detect [radeon]] *ERROR* HDMI-A-1: probed a monitor but no|invalid EDID  
 [Tue Aug 22 03:18:46 2023] EDID has corrupt header
```

I did test it with a live-USB distro where the monitor *was* working before
(to make sure it wasn't just some messed up configuration in my kde plasma desktop environment or whatever),
but it doesn't work there either.

And after googling a bit,
it seems that apparently this *is* an actual known problem?
Like, the actual data in the EEPROM memory chip in a monitor itself can get corrupted while plugging the monitor in and out and stuff?
(Well, *I'm* personally pretty surprised and confused to learn that.)

---

But apparently that data,
the monitor just gives it to the computer,
so that the computer knows what different settings the monitor can do (in terms of resolution/refresh-rate/etc),
and then the computer uses it to decide what signal it sends to the monitor and how

-- but I'm not sure whether the monitor plays any further active role at that point,
or just "passively" displays whatever signal it receives from the computer...?
(
ie, I'm not sure
(assuming I can get a file with a *non*-corrupt EDID for the monitor)
whether:

- (1) I would need to actually write that data back onto the chip in the monitor somehow(?)
- (2) or if I could just tell the operating system like:
  "I know the EDID data you're getting from the monitor is wrong, so use this file instead"

... ?
)

---

Also, I don't know how I *can* get a file with a *non*-corrupt EDID for the monitor?
Like, it's a "**Samsung SyncMaster B2030**",
and I was able to google up copies of EDID files for *other* monitors,
but not for this specific model...?

(I *did* find a `.exe` file for the Windows drivers (I think), so could I maybe extract the data from *that* somehow??)

Comment: Could it be a hardware issue? A loose or broken cable?

Comment: @Jos Hm, it seems unlikely to be a hardware issue with the cable/plug, since the problem started while I was messing with the rotation in the the *software* (with `xrandr`), not while I was messing with the *physical* position/rotation/tilt/swivel of the monitor... right? And this problem with corrupt EDID data on the EEPROM chip in the monitor needing to be fixed or worked-around apparently *is* a known problem -- I'm just not sure how to try *implementing* the solution...